# Negative weight paint on a skeleton?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

[image: Trouble Explanation]

Hi,

I have a skeleton's strange distortion on my character's knee.

How I can apply "Negative Weight Paint" to limit this strange hole between my character's knee and calf ? Weight Paint is already set to the minimum.

Thanks a lot for your support guys

Comment: You can't give negative value. Here the issue is due to the bone placement the kneecap in inside the thigh

Comment: thanks for your support !!!!!!!!!